# Executing a Thread in Asynctask and its complications

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, thread-safety

I was wondering is it ok to execute a `Thread` inside the `doInBackground` method of `Asynctask`. Should I avoid using this kind of structure on my codes? And if yes, why should I avoid it? Would this cause any ineffectiveness in my apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*In principle*, there's no problem with starting a thread in the `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask`, but sometimes you see this done not because it's the right thing to do, but because of a misunderstanding about how `AsyncTask` works.

The point is that `doInBackground()` will *automatically* get executed on a background (non-GUI) thread, without you needing to create a thread for it yourself. That, in fact, is the whole point of an `AsyncTask`. So if you have a simple, linear task that you want executed in the background, you do it with an `AsyncTask`, and you don't need to do any manual thread creation.

Where you *might* want to start a new thread in an `AsyncTask` is if you want your background task to use multiple threads to complete. Suppose that you were writing an app to check the online status of various servers, and display something about their status on the screen. You'd use an `AsyncTask` to do the network access in the background; but if you did it in a naive way, you'd end up with the servers being pinged one by one, which would be rather slow (especially if one was down, and you needed to wait for a timeout). The better option would be to make sure that each server was dealt with on its own background thread. You'd then have a few options, each of which would be defensible:

1. Have a separate `AsyncTask` for each server.
2. Create a thread for each server inside the `doInBackground()` of your single `AsyncTask`, and then make sure that `doInBackground()` doesn't complete until all the individual threads have completed (use `Thread.join()`).
3. Use a `ThreadPool` / some kind of `ExecutorService` / a fork/join structure inside your single `AsyncTask`, to manage the threads for you.

I would say that with modern libraries there is rarely a need for manual thread creation. Library functions will manage all of this for you, and take some of the tedium out of it, and make it less error-prone. The third option above is functionally equivalent to the second, but just uses more of the high-level machinery that you've been given, rather than going DIY with your thread creation.

I'm not saying that threads should never be created manually, but whenever you're tempted to create one, it's well worth asking whether there's a high-level option that will do it for you more easily and more safely.

Answer (score 3):

> is it ok to execute a Thread inside the doInBackground method of
>   Asynctask.

yes it is but it really depends on your application and your usage. for example in a multithread `server-client` app you must create for each incoming clients one `thread` and also you must listen on another `thread`. so creating `thread` inside another is ok. and you can use `asynctask` for listening to your clients.

> Should I avoid using this kind of structure on my codes? And if yes,
>   why should I avoid it?

If you design it carefully you do not need to avoid, for example make sure that on rotation you do not create another `asynctask` because for example if your user rotates 5 times you create 5 `asynctasks` and in each of them you create a `thread` that means you will get 10 `threads`, soon you will get memory leak.

> Would this cause any ineffectiveness in my apps? Can you explain
>   these questions please.

I answered it above, I think better idea is using `Thread Pool` to minimize number of creating your `threads` or wraping your `asynctask` in a `UI less fragment` so you are sure you have one `asynctask` regardless of whats going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

In any higher programming language, there is concept of multi-tasking. Basically the user needs to run some portion of code without user interaction. A thread is generally developed for that. But in Android, multi-tasking can be done by any of the three methods `Thread` and `AsyncTask`.

**Thread**

A thread is a concurrent unit of execution. It has its own call stack. There are two methods to implement threads in applications.

One is providing a new class that extends Thread and overriding its run() method.
The other is providing a new Thread instance with a Runnable object during its creation.
A thread can be executed by calling its "start" method. You can set the "Priority" of a thread by calling its "setPriority(int)" method.

A thread can be used if you have no affect in the UI part. For example, you are calling some web service or download some data, and after download, you are displaying it to your screen. Then you need to use a Handler with a Thread and this will make your application complicated to handle all the responses from Threads.

A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each thread has each message queue. (Like a To do List), and the thread will take each message and process it until the message queue is empty. So, when the Handler communicates, it just gives a message to the caller thread and it will wait to process.

If you use Java threads then you need to handle the following requirements in your own code:

- Synchronization with the main thread if you post back results to the user interface
- No default for canceling the thread
- No default thread pooling
- No default for handling configuration changes in Android

**AsyncTask**

AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows performing background operations and publishing results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers. An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread.

AsyncTask will go through the following 4 stages:

**1. onPreExecute()**

Invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed

**2. doInbackground(Params..)**

Invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing.

**3. onProgressUpdate(Progress..)**

Invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...).

**4. onPostExecute(Result)**

Invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes.

And there are lot of good resources over internet which may help you:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html http://www.mergeconflict.net/2012/05/java-threads-vs-android-asynctask-which.html

Comment: It is also important to note that the Android OS prevents the user from executing resource-heavy process such as Network related ones (downloading, uploading, etc) to be executed in the Main Thread or the User Interface (UI) Thread to prevent lag. In such cases, the use of Async Tasks are required.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there is no problem in doing that if you need something to run concurrently beside the `AsyncTask`.

One issue could be one of readability (using 2 different ways for concurrency), but I really can't see the harm in that - especially if one of the tasks needs to show it's result in the UI and the other one doesn't.